# What's the function behind Dart's hashCode function for a String?

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to write a hash function in a new language that would be compatible with Dart's internal String.hashCode function. To do this, I need to know what the function responsible for generating the hashCode function is. I've tried to check the docs, but I can't really find anything (probably looking in the wrong places, but there are a lot of places to look).

Comment: What would you use that "compatible" hash function? You can look up the source in the Dart SDK source to see how exactly it is calculated.

Comment: That is exactly my question - I'm having trouble "look[ing] up the source in the Dart SDK source to see how exactly it is calculated"

Comment: What do you want to use it anyway?

Comment: `external` means it uses the JS implementation when run in the browser and a C/C++ implementation from the VM otherwise. I'm still curious what you want to use it for because you might make common wrong assumptions that would render your use case invalid anyway and further search pointless.

Comment: I have a dart/flutter cross platform app which uses the hashcode. Are you implying that the hashcode of it running on android software would be different than iOS software?

Comment: Usually when people ask about hashcode they assume that it is unique which is not true. 2 different strings can have the same hashcode. If the feature you plan depends on hashcodes being unique you can just drop the approach and look for a new one. I assume the hascode calculation will be the same between iOS and Android but I wouldn't expect any guarantees here. I could also imagine that it can change from one Dart version to the next (could be wrong). HashCode is used to make HashMaps more efficient. If you are using it for something else, it's likely not doing what you want.